# How to delete the first object from a JSON file

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to make a queue in node js and want to delete the first JSON object in my JSON file.

I create and store users in a JSON file and then add them in the queue JSON file by reading the users.json. The problem is that when i get the user from user.json it comes as an object within an array, and i cant filter to compare the id. So how can i do this?

```
// helper method to read JSON FILE.
    const readFile = (callback, returnJson = false, filePath = dataPath, encoding = 'utf8') => { 
        fs.readFile(filePath, encoding, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            callback(returnJson ? JSON.parse(data) : data);
        });
    }; 

    // helper method to write on JSON FILE.
    const writeFile = (fileData, callback, filePath = dataPath, encoding = 'utf8') => {

        fs.writeFile(filePath, fileData, encoding, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            callback();
        });
    };

// thats how i try to delete first user from the queue, but it deletes the user with index 1.

 app.delete('/popLine', (req, res) => {

        readFile(data => {

            //const userId = req.params["id"];
            delete data[1]; // remove the first element from the Line.

            writeFile(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), () => {
                res.status(200).send(`queue id: removed`);
            });
        },
            true);
    });

// thats how an user is stored in queue.json
"5": [
    {
      "name": "teresa may",
      "email": "parliament",
      "gender": "male",
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
```

Comment: You need to show more information if we are to help you.  According to your data sample, you're using string-based keys.  But you're deleting a numeric index of `1`.  "and i cant filter to compare the id"  Why not?  Also, while you can do this, it's not the most efficient way.  Have you considered a small file-based database like SQLite?  It supports structured data with its JSON extension as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer loading the JSON file as a JSON object (if its manageable) then delete the first entry by key and then persisting the file back on the disk (over-write) periodically or instantaneously which be necessary.

You can do a **require** to load a JSON file as a JSON object. But note, if you do a re-**require** of the changed file to reload it again during runtime, it will not get you the changes you made to the file in between but the older content from last **require**. In that case you need to clear the item from the **require** cache before getting the changes.

I am assuming the file is in order of KBs.. for larger files I wouldn’t prefer this approach, rather I would figure a way out to get that file data in a NoSQL document database.

Hope this helps :)