# How to get the position of an object in an array?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get the position in array of the first object so i can delete it with a function. The problem is: i don't know how to get the "index"value.

```
{
  "2": {
    "nome": "sou1",
    "email": "adsa@lala.com",
    "gênero": "masculino",
    "id": 1,
    "pos": 0
  },
  "3": {
    "nome": "sou1",
    "email": "adsa@lala.com",
    "gênero": "masculino",
    "id": 1,
    "pos": 1
  }
}
```

In this case, my output would be 2.

Comment: Position of what object?

Comment: Objects have no inherent ordering.  Use an array?

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57739733/362536

Comment: Title says, "_How to get the position of an object in an array?_," but there are no arrays in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below

```
var someObject={
"2": {
  "nome": "sou1",
  "email": "adsa@lala.com",
  "gênero": "masculino",
  "id": 1,
  "pos": 0
},
"3": {
  "nome": "sou1",
  "email": "adsa@lala.com",
  "gênero": "masculino",
  "id": 1,
  "pos": 1
}};
console.log(Object.keys(someObject)[0]);
  delete someObject[Object.keys(someObject)[0]];
  console.log(someObject);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what i want to do!

Answer (score 0):

There is no ordering in JSON objects.
However, for your use case (if I correctly understand that), you can convert the JSON object into an array doing...

```
const someObject = {
    a: "A",
    b: "B",
    c: "C"
}

const keys = Object.keys(someObject);
console.log(keys); // array of keys

let arr = [];
for(key of keys) {
    arr.push(someObject[key]);
}

console.log(arr); // array of objects
```

...where the index of an element in the `keys` array  (a key in your original JSON object) will be identical to the index of an element in the `arr` array (the corresponding value for that key in your original JSON object) which it maps to in your original JSON object, in a way giving you what you probably are looking for. Then you can access them using the array indices.

Hope this helps :)